# Compare Validation for dates of format dd-MMM-yyyy

Tags: c#, javascript

I'm having two text boxes. One contains the start date and the other contains the end date. Both of the text boxes are in `dd-MMM-yyyy` date format. My requirement is to compare these two dates and if the To date is less than the From date i have to throw an exception(I must not proceed further if To date < than From Date).

I have used compare validator, but it doesn't work.
so I have tried to do the validation using java script.But it is not working for some days.

I have written the script as:

```
function ValidateDate() {
        var fromdate = document.getElementById("txtStartDate");
        var todate = document.getElementById("txtEndDate");

        var startDate = fromdate.value;
        var endDate = todate.value;


        if (endDate < startDate) {
            alert("Please ensure that the End Date is greater than or equal to the Start Date.");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Please any one of you provide a solution for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For what days doesn't it work? Is there a pattern? Please provide examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got the solution Friends...

What I have done is I just  parsed the date to milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC. I have parsed for both the dates and compared those two values..

The solution for it is:

```
function ValidateDate() {
        var fromdate = document.getElementById("txtFromDate");
        var todate = document.getElementById("txtToDate");
        var endDate = todate.value;
        var startDate = fromdate.value;

        /* Convert the date 01-Jan-1991 to Jan 1, 1991 */

        var splitdate = startDate.split("-");
        var dt1 = splitdate[1] + " " + splitdate[0] + ", " + splitdate[2];
        var splitdate = endDate.split("-");
        var dt2 = splitdate[1] + " " + splitdate[0] + ", " + splitdate[2];

        var newStartDate = Date.parse(dt1); //Parse the date to  milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC
        var newEndDate = Date.parse(dt2);

        if (newStartDate > newEndDate ) {
            alert("Please ensure that the End Date is greater than or equal to the Start Date.");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use of Jquery here can be lot easier.

```
var fromdate = document.getElementById("txtStartDate");
    var todate = document.getElementById("txtEndDate");

if ($.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', fromdate) > $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', todate)) {

       alert(fromdate+ 'is greater than ' + todate);

}
```

Check [THIS](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/?rdfrom=http://docs.jquery.com/mw/index.php?title=UI/Datepicker/parseDate&redirect=no) doccument.

Answer (score 1):

To compare two dates, c# provides a method to compare them. [DateTime.Compare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare.aspx). It returns an int value to check if the first is earlier, the same or later than the second.

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2013, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime date2 = new DateTime(2013, 8, 1, 12, 0, 0);
int result = DateTime.Compare(date1, date2);

if (result < 0)
{
    // date1 is earlier than date2;
}
else if (result == 0)
{
    // date1 is the same time as date2
}
else
{
    // date1 is later than date2
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: If you want to do it in javascript you can use the Date Object. You can compare them like Dates, or get the time in miliseconds with the "getTime" method and compare them like integers. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need to convert the textboxes' values to `Date` before you can compare them. Otherwise, you would be just comparing their lexicographical order.

```
var startDate = Date.parse(fromdate.value);
var endDate = Date.parse(todate.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like.

```
function CompareDates(str1,str2) 

{ 

    if(str1 == "")

        return false;

   var dt1   = parseInt(str1.substring(0,2),10); 

   var mon1  = parseInt(str1.substring(3,5),10);

   var yr1   = parseInt(str1.substring(6,10),10); 

   var dt2   = parseInt(str2.substring(0,2),10); 

   var mon2  = parseInt(str2.substring(3,5),10); 

   var yr2   = parseInt(str2.substring(6,10),10); 

   mon1 = mon1 -1 ;

   mon2 = mon2 -1 ;

   var date1 = new Date(yr1, mon1, dt1); 

   var date2 = new Date(yr2, mon2, dt2); 



   if(date2 >= date1)

   {

        return false; 

   } 

   else 

   { 

        return true;

   } 

}
```